# Discrepancy in .net versions in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm attempting to update .net from version 5 to version 6.  I'm using Visual Studio Code and when I build and debug, I see

```
OmniSharp server started with .NET 6.0.201
```

But in my output window but in my Debug Console, I still see references to version 5:

```
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.15\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

This isn't the case in visual studio which shows

```
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.3\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

I've specified in my `.proj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>CS_Test</RootNamespace>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;Linux</Configurations>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <DockerfileContext>.</DockerfileContext>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Is there something else I'm overlooking for vscode?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RuikaiFeng I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean; I'm rather new to the .net/visual studio world.

Comment: Sorry,I want suggest you to check the sdk you referred is correct,but the link seems was not copied in my comment

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  These were set in [projectname]/.vs/launch.json under configurations>program.

I just changed it from `"program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net5.0/csr_portal.dll",` to `"program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net6.0/csr_portal.dll",` and that was it!